# Change hand IK over time instead of it just snapping to 0 and 1

Tags: unity-game-engine, inverse-kinematics

I'm trying to get my characters rig to go from hand IK 0 to 1 over a period of time instead of just snapping to it. How could I go about doing that?

```cs
public TwoBoneIKConstraint rightHandIK;  //on animator manager script // getting hand IK from inspector so can change weight
public TwoBoneIKConstraint leftHandIK;   //on animator manager script

    if (animatorManager.isAimingGunn)
{
    animatorManager.leftHandIK.weight = 1; 
    animatorManager.rightHandIK.weight = 1; 
    horizontalMovementInput = 0f;
    verticalMovementInput = 0f;
}
else if(animatorManager.isAimingGunn == false)
{
    animatorManager.rightHandIK.weight = 0;
    animatorManager.leftHandIK.weight = 0; 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you need to run a **Tweener**. This is a basic float Tweener that smoothly changes the floats by running Coroutine.

```cs
public IEnumerator DoTween(Func<float> getter , Action<float> setter, float targetValue, float duringTime = 1f)
{
    var progress = 0f;

    var init = getter();
    
    while (progress < 1)
    {
        progress += Time.deltaTime/duringTime;

        setter.Invoke(Mathf.Lerp(init, targetValue, progress));

        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
    }
}
```

---

Do this to run Tweener in if code, Also, to zero the weight only, set zero in the targetValue parameter:

```cs
// How to run tweener?
// for E.G set IK weight to 1 during 2 seconds

StartCoroutine(DoTween(
    () => animatorManager.leftHandIK.weight, 
    x => animatorManager.leftHandIK.weight = x,
    1f, 2f
));
```

Also, if you want to create similar effects in the code, it suggests using the great [DoTween](http://dotween.demigiant.com/index.php) unity plug-in.

Comment: what do these mean Func<float> getter , Action<float> setter?

Comment: @DrakenForge37 They act like a lambda, with Action <Float> you can set your command based on the moving float.

Comment: Could I get an example please. I cut and paste the code,but im getting an error with Func<float> getter and Action<float> setter

Comment: ops.. you need `using System` ;

Comment: Sorry, I have no idea what happened. This code gives you a smooth float motion. If there is no problem in this regard, you have taken a step forward. If the problem is with the pebbles and IKs, you need to improve the code. The question you asked will be resolved with Tweener.

Comment: looks like it has to do with my recoil animation . might be because its on the override layer.